# Is log4j2 Console appender synchrounous

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

In general `System.out.println` methods are synchronized so it is not advised to use them.

How about log4j2 Console appender - is using the console appender have the same effect or performance impact as using `System.out.println`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. See the source code of [ConsoleAppender.java](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/aac288297f7a3c8828cf39ba7753224089d5371d/log4j-core/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/ConsoleAppender.java). It calls *System.out* or *System.err*.

If you're looking for async behaviour, you can wrap ConsoleAppender with an [AsyncAppender](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#AsyncAppender).

Answer (score 0):

Yes Console appender uses the `System.out` and `System.err` streams.

In terms of performance, it is about 50x slower than writing to a file. (I kid you not: 20,000 msg/sec for console vs 1 M msg/sec for FileAppender on Linux).